# Docker, monitoring container status, alerts

Tags: docker, monitoring, nagios, zabbix

Is there any monitoring system for docker which "out of the box" supports sending alerts(email/smth else) in case of "Container#111 is down"? 
Or does implementation through the Nagios/Zabbix more right way?

Comment: I would recommend you to rephrase the question as per posting guidelines of stack overflow. You would get better responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker doesn't provide any "alerting" feature. It's task for your monitoring tool.

**Zabbix world:**

Zabbix supports email, SMS, ...  out of the box + you have community scripts, which can be used as well: http://monitoringartist.github.io/zabbix-searcher/#script_alert

Docker monitoring solutions for Zabbix:
http://monitoringartist.github.io/zabbix-searcher/#docker

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Sematext Docker Agent. It's open source and will collect your Docker logs, metrics, and events (and more, but check the readme for more).  URL: https://github.com/sematext/sematext-agent-docker